Questions related to dictionaries
# My dictionary 
potato_shop = {
    "PCT16": [
        "Standard Potatoes",
        {"SP12": ["Plain Potato", 1.20], "SP67": ["Cream Potato", 1.75]},
    ],
    "PCT44": [
        "Premium Potatoes",
        {
            "PP18": ["Chocolate Cheese Potato", 3.20],
            "PP91": ["Whipped Cream Strawberry Potato", 5.00],
        },
    ],
}

If I were to type in Plain Potato for example, how would I get the value of 1.20?

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries (also note https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/3001761 - please take the [tour] and read [ask]).

What do you mean "If I were to type in..."? Do you mean, how can you get the value from the dictionary?

Since your dictionary is nested (by potato category), you'd need to traverse it "by hand" to find Plain Potato's value.

To get to 1.20 you would have to type potato_shop["PCT16"][1]["SP12"][1]. Your dictionaries are nested in lists, nested in dictionaries, nested in lists, nested in a dictionary. Honestly, you couldn't have made it much harder to get data.

A normal pattern for Python lists is that their contents should be homogeneous. You're making things difficult for yourself with this design

Since your dictionary is nested (by potato category), you'd need to traverse it "by hand" to find a product by name, and then return the desired value.
potato_shop = {
    "PCT16": [
        "Standard Potatoes",
        {"SP12": ["Plain Potato", 1.20], "SP67": ["Cream Potato", 1.75]},
    ],
    "PCT44": [
        "Premium Potatoes",
        {
            "PP18": ["Chocolate Cheese Potato", 3.20],
            "PP91": ["Whipped Cream Strawberry Potato", 5.00],
        },
    ],
}


def find_product_value(name_to_find):
    for category_id, (category_name, category_products) in potato_shop.items():
        for product_sku, (product_name, product_value) in category_products.items():
            if product_name == name_to_find:
                return product_value
    raise KeyError(f"Product {name_to_find} not found")


print(find_product_value("Plain Potato"))

prints out 1.2 as expected.
For a more involved project, I'd probably flatten this tree into a list of dataclasses, to make lookups nicer:


@dataclasses.dataclass
class PotatoProduct:
    sku: str
    name: str
    value: float
    category_id: str
    category_name: str


def flatten_shop(shop):
    for category_id, (category_name, category_products) in shop.items():
        for product_sku, (product_name, product_value) in category_products.items():
            yield PotatoProduct(
                sku=product_sku,
                name=product_name,
                value=product_value,
                category_name=category_name,
                category_id=category_id,
            )


for product in flatten_shop(potato_shop):
    print(product)
    if product.name == "Plain Potato":
        print("The value of", product.name, "is", product.value)

prints out
PotatoProduct(sku='SP12', name='Plain Potato', value=1.2, category_id='PCT16', category_name='Standard Potatoes')
The value of Plain Potato is 1.2
PotatoProduct(sku='SP67', name='Cream Potato', value=1.75, category_id='PCT16', category_name='Standard Potatoes')
PotatoProduct(sku='PP18', name='Chocolate Cheese Potato', value=3.2, category_id='PCT44', category_name='Premium Potatoes')
PotatoProduct(sku='PP91', name='Whipped Cream Strawberry Potato', value=5.0, category_id='PCT44', category_name='Premium Potatoes')


Thank you ❤️. As a very newbie python learner I really appreciate it.

@PengPeng Please accept this answer with the green checkmark to show your gratitude & indicate the problem's been solved!
